# Completing the Morphia/MongoDB example code

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I've been trying to get the example code from the Morphia Website working with very little success, I was wondering why the following code snippet fails?

```
public class DBUtil {
    private static Mongo mongo;
    private static Datastore ds;
    private static Morphia morphia;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(Consts.DatabaseHost,
                    Consts.DatabasePort));

            morphia = new Morphia();

            morphia.map(Employee.class);

            ds = morphia.createDatastore(mongo, Consts.DatabaseName);

            DB db = Mongo.connect(new DBAddress(Consts.DatabaseHost,
                    Consts.DatabasePort, Consts.DatabaseName));

            ds.save(new Employee("Mister", "GOD", null, 0));

            // get an employee without a manager
            Employee boss = ds.find(Employee.class).field("manager")
                    .equal(null).get();

            Key<Employee> scottsKey = ds.save(new Employee("Scott",
                    "Hernandez", ds.getKey(boss), 150 * 1000));

            // add Scott as an employee of his manager
            UpdateResults<Employee> res = ds.update(
                    boss,
                    ds.createUpdateOperations(Employee.class).add("underlings",
                            scottsKey));

            // get Scott's boss; the same as the one above.
            Employee scottsBoss = ds.find(Employee.class)
                    .filter("underlings", scottsKey).get();

            for (Employee e : ds.find(Employee.class, "manager", boss))
                    System.out.println(e);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

when using the following for the employee class?

```
@Entity("employees")
class Employee {
  public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, Object object, int i) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      manager = new Key<Employee>(Employee.class, object);
    }

  // auto-generated, if not set (see ObjectId)
  @Id ObjectId id;

  // value types are automatically persisted
  String firstName, lastName;

  // only non-null values are stored
  Long salary = null;

  // by default fields are @Embedded
  Address address;

  //references can be saved without automatic loading
  Key<Employee> manager;

  //refs are stored**, and loaded automatically
  @Reference List<Employee> underlings = new ArrayList<Employee>();

  // stored in one binary field
  //@Serialized EncryptedReviews;

  //fields can be renamed
  @Property("started") Date startDate;
  @Property("left") Date endDate;

  //fields can be indexed for better performance
  @Indexed boolean active = false;

  //fields can loaded, but not saved
  @NotSaved String readButNotStored;

  //fields can be ignored (no load/save)
  @Transient int notStored;

  //not @Transient, will be ignored by Serialization/GWT for example.
  transient boolean stored = true;
}
```

However when use the above code, the 'get an employee without a manager' line fails to locate anything and the update operation throws an exception. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think it should be `Employee boss = ds.find(Employee.class).field("manager").doesNotExist().get();`
2. If I'm not mistaken, entities should have a no-args constructor.

PS: If you want to get started with a complete project quickly, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/xeraa/mongouk2011

Comment: So I downloaded your project and noticed that it successfully saves the entities to the DB.  I've since used your code to back track and realise that my use of GWT in the project has been getting in the way because I've been using a String for the @Id and this breaks morphia.  v1.02 of morphia for GWT simply doesn't work.